# How to Configure web service client endpoint url?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-7, wsdl, reverse-proxy, endpoint

We have a situation, our interface partner is calling our web service dynamically by calling our WSDL and consume web methods by using the endpoint defined in the WSDL.

Here, the problem is - As we are using reverse proxy server, the actual web service is hosted in different content server and have URL rewrite rule configured in proxy server to redirect the request to real content server. Our interface partner is successfully consumed our WSDL by using the given reverse proxy URL, but the WSDL is having the real content server URL and our interface partner is not having access to it.

They can change the endpoint url in their proxy class and consume the web service via the reverse proxy URL; unfortunately, they are using some common framework to dynamically build the end point from the received WSDL. So our client could not consume our web service.

Is there any way to determine the client's endpoint url in web service? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

open wsdl file in browser. save as on local system with .wsdl extension. in client code give url of local file instead of server address as given below.

url = new URL("file:/C:/apps/Services.wsdl");